# List View Threshold limit with "Read items that were created by the user"

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view-threshold

With the option "Read items that were created by the user" on a SharePoint list I was not expecting users to hit the 5,000 item List View Threshold limit.

In this scenario are the list items filtered after retrieving the entire list? The default view did have a sort on a Date column which isn't indexed though no user will have input anywhere near the 5,000 item limit.

Creating a view which uses a filter of "Created By = [Me]" works perfectly fine and states "Created By" is indexed so I'm confused.

Comment: To determine how many items you have in the List, take a look in the Site Contents menu - scroll down until you find the List, then you will see how many items exist, without items being filtered out by Views or whatever else.  BTW - Certain views might not function because they may show over the 5,000 item limit. while other views might still work because they are under the limit.

Comment: Yes there is just over 5,000 items though with that option enabled I wouldn't expect over 5,000 items to be returned

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, i was understood like. whenever user trying open the list, you don't want to load your threshold value limit (5000), you looking for some option to filter the list item based on the created by. For that you applied the filter like "Created By =[Me]"

If so, you have another option to filter based on the Created By without filtering the item.

You can navigate to List setting -> Advance Setting -> you can see Item level permissions. so you can declare as mentioned below. so that only the creater can see their items..

[image]

Let me know if i miss understood your question

Comment: Those options are already enabled which is why I was surprised to hit the 5,000 item limit. I believe the issue was because the default view had a sort applied on a Date column which isn't indexed.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [this link](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-overcome-sharepoint-5000-item-limit-threshold/) useful, it's by a blogger I very much like.  There's quite a lot to read and I won't repeat what he says.

The blogger, the SP Maven, also has a [slide deck](https://www.slideshare.net/gzelfond/sharepoint-5000-item-list-view-threshold-checklist-and-best-practices) which you might find to be more digestible.